# Need help getting on windows and uninstalling ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, windows, uninstall

Im using a Hp pavilion dm1 and I installed ubuntu using a usb stick because my laptop doesnt have a disk drive, I installed ubuntu on a new partition and chose to copy my files to it when installing. But when I looked through my documents I couldnt find any of my files. My firefox keeps freezing my laptop and its screwing me over. I cant get back onto windows 7 for some reason, ive tried many things.

Is there a way for me to uninstall ubuntu and get windows 7 back with all my files? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to? Better solve the problem with Firefox, because it is not normal.
Your documents are residing on your Windows partition, unless you removed it during installation. In latter case your documents are in backup. Just copy them manually. You can access Windows partitions from Files, there is a list of devices on the left.

---

You do not need to "uninstall Ubuntu" unless you've done strange things to your disk like LVM encryption. Just repair Windows bootloader and you will have it back again. Or install Windows anew.